# Combine object values and create array

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks in the following format with a lot of data

```
const obj = {
  firstItem1: "Main",
  secondItem2: "Something",
  thirdItem3: "",
  firstItemNumber1: "test",
  secondItemNumber2: "bx",
  thirdItemNumber3: ""    
}
```

If the string is empty, ignore it and dont add to array I would like to return it in the following format

```
firstItem1 firstItemNumber1
```

Output should be an array of strings.

```
["Main test", "Something bx"]
```

Comment: Object.values(obj)

Comment: Looks like a very wild task judging from the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const obj = {
    firstItem1: "Main",
    secondItem2: "Something",
    thirdItem3: "",
    firstItemNumber1: "test",
    secondItemNumber2: "bx",
    thirdItemNumber3: "",
    forthItemNumber: "bbb",
    forthItem : "aaa",
};

function filterValues(obj) {
    var data = [];
    var serials = [];

    for (let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key];
        let pos = key.indexOf("Item") + 4;
        let serial = key.slice(0, pos);
        if (!value || value == "" || serials.includes(serial) || key.includes("Number")) continue;

        let name = key.slice(0, pos);
        let num = key.slice(pos);

        let val1 = obj[name + num];
        let val2 = obj[name + "Number" + num];
        data.push(val1 + " " + val2);
        
        serials.push(serial);
    }

    return data;
}

console.log(filterValues(obj));
```

Here, I loop through the whole object using `for...in` loop, then inside the loop

**1.**  First thing, parse the name and number of the key.
For example, in the first key i.e., **firstItem1**, we parse the name as `firstItem` and number as `1`, by finding the index of **Item** inside the key string and using slice method.

```
let pos = key.indexOf("Item") + 4;
let name = key.slice(0, pos);
let num = key.slice(pos);
```

**2.** Then, store the value of current key and corresponding required key, by joining the name and num for current key and name ,"Number" string
and num for corresponding value as

```
let val1 = obj[name + num]; // firstItem1
let val2 = obj[name + "Number" + num]; // firstItemNumber1
```

**3.** Then, join the `val1` and `val2` with a space and push into the output array.

**4.** Now at last, add a `if` statement to **continue** the loop  under following conditions:-

1. when value is emty
2. when key string ie., **firstItem1**, contains '*Number*' keyword
3. when it is already added, for example :- `firstItem1` and `firstItemNumber1`. To identify them, both have a same serial number i.e., **first**, so I stored them in an array `serials` array and check if it already included.

Thanks to `Kirilo Lozitsky` for his comment ;D

Comment: It's wrong answer, because your result is `["Main Something","test bx"]`, not `["Main test", "Something bx"]`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get `keys` and `values` of the `obj`, then group it by the number `first, second, third, ...`, with `reduce` method, To be in this format.

```
{
   first: ['Main', 'test'],
   second: ['Something', 'bx']
}
```

Then get `values` from this Object, and `join` it with a space.

```js
let numbers = ["first", "second", "third"];



const obj = {
  firstItem1: "Main",
  secondItem2: "Something",
  thirdItem3: "",
  firstItemNumber1: "test",
  secondItemNumber2: "bx",
  thirdItemNumber3: ""    
}

const result = Object.values(Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    let number = numbers.find(n => key.startsWith(n))
    if (value !== '') {
      acc[number] ? acc[number].push(value) : (acc[number] = [value])
    }
    return acc;
}, {})).map(i => i.join(' '))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking to merge the values as well. 
The first element of the expected output  = 'Main test' which concatenates values of the keys "firstItem1" and "firstItemNumber1"

Comment: Thanks for notifying, may I misunderstand the task,  I just update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the array of object fields, use:

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

If you want to receive the array of object values, use:

```
Object.values(obj)
```

In your case, you can use `Object.entries(obj)`, it returns you array of array with key and value. Logic of iteration you can find below.

You need to **specify/give us** **the rule/logic** how to map field to field - by name, etc..

```
const obj = {
  firstItem1: "Main",
  secondItem2: "Something",
  thirdItem3: "",
  firstItemNumber1: "test",
  secondItemNumber2: "bx",
  thirdItemNumber3: ""    
};
Object.entries(obj).filter(arr => {
    const [field, value] = arr
    return value?.length; // remove empty strings
}).map((arr, index, originalArray) => {
    const [field, value] = arr
    //return your string here by your specific rule/logic
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys from object by using [Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then store the strings with similar names and using array map and filter you can return the desired result.

```js
const obj = {
  firstItem1: "Main",
  secondItem2: "Something",
  thirdItem3: "",
  firstItemNumber1: "test",
  secondItemNumber2: "bx",
  thirdItemNumber3: ""    
};

const strArray = Object.keys(obj);

const tempArray = [];

const getSimilarKeys = arr => arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(!item.includes('Number')){
    tempArray.push(item);
  }
});

getSimilarKeys(strArray);

const result = tempArray.map((item, index) => obj[item] + ' ' +  obj[`${item.substring(0, item.length - 1)}Number${index+1}`]).filter(item => item !== ' ');


console.log('result ', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution.

```js
const obj = {
    firstItem1: "Main",
    secondItem2: "Something",
    thirdItem3: "",
    firstItemNumber1: "test",
    secondItemNumber2: "bx",
    thirdItemNumber3: ""
}

    const someArr = Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, next) => 
    !next.includes('Number') && obj[next] 
      ? (arr.push(`${obj[next]}, ${obj[next.toString().replace('Item', 'ItemNumber')]}`), arr) 
      : arr, []);

console.log(someArr);
```